# MySQL Select between an unknown number of date intervals

Tags: mysql

I currently have two tables, one is called games, the other called rounds. Here is the structure to help out:

rounds

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| schedule_id | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| open_date   | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| close_date  | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date  | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date    | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

games

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| schedule_id | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| team_a      | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| team_b      | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| winner      | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date        | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now the rounds table is a bunch of rounds with specified date ranges, and games are set within the round date range (but not always). Anyways, What I want to do is select all games between multiple round intervals. So if I have three round intervals,

```
round 1 - nov 13 to nov 15
round 2 - nov 20 to nov 25
round 3 - dec 1 to nov 10
```

how do I only select the games that are between those date periods without doing multiple SQL statements. Essentially I want something like this in the end:

```
SELECT * 
FROM games 
WHERE date BETWEEN round1.start_date AND round1.end_date OR
      date BETWEEN round2.start_date AND round2.end_date OR
      date BETWEEN round3.start_date AND round3.end_date
```

but I don't know how many rounds I will have. I also cannot use a max a min because there might be rounds between those intervals that I do not want. Right now my only solution is that I do one select for all the rounds, then do a select for each interval through PHP. I am hoping that there might be a better, more efficient way to accomplish this.

Hopefully this made sense and thanks!

### Update:

After posting this question, I had an idea of a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM games INNER JOIN 
     rounds ON games.`date` BETWEEN rounds.start_date AND rounds.end_date
```

does something like that make sense? It seems to work, but I've never joined like that, so I don't know what type of effects I might encounter.

Comment: I don't see any keys in your schema that relate to `rounds`. If they are simply a logical grouping, I don't believe you can do this with SQL alone.

Comment: It is just a logical grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close with your update...

```
select `games`.* from games join rounds on (`games`.`date` < `rounds`.`end_date` AND `games`.`date` > `rounds`.`start_date`);
```

Comment: But "between" essentially does the same with less code from my understanding. Is there a performance gain by doing it your way?

Comment: I was under the impression between wasn't working for you, if between is working then performance wise they should be the same with the exception that I have my choice to use > >= < <= to include or not include the start and end dates or get the dates between only.  Which between seems to use <= >=.

Comment: ok. Yea, I want it inclusive, but I was just worried that I was getting optimization all wrong.

Comment: So just to update this answer; my update was correct and using "between" is the solution in my scenario. But this answer does have its merits in having the flexibility of either inclusive or exclusivity and hence why I’d set this as the answer to my question.

Comment: For the record, if you run mysql from the commandline and add the word 'explain' in front of it, eg.  'explain select * from ....' you'll see more information on how many rows it goes through, which indexes it uses, etc.  If you run explain for both queries, they are identical in the number of rows and indexes.  Which any time you do joins, you should run an explain and make sure its not filtering through a crazy amount of rows, or its properly joining on indexes, or else your queries will be slow.